# How to restart linux services if it reaches 100% CPU?

Tags: linux, cpu-usage, kill, saslauthd

I have postfix email server with saslauthd. Time and again saslauthd daemon eats 100% CPU. Restarting these services returns to normal cpu usage.

Is there any proper script to determine services with high CPU usage and restart it automatically.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Don't fix the symptom. Find the cause and fix that

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. But there seems issue with saslauthd latest version.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/cyrus-sasl2/+bug/997217

And I haven't found proper way to fix it.

Comment: That bug has been fixed five years ago. If you are affected by it, apply an update.

Comment: I have latest version of Cyrus-Sasl. 2.1.26. same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to take a look at `monit` ([official site](https://mmonit.com/monit/)).

It's easily configurable to watch for high CPU usage and restart processes when needed.

A simple example (you should configure it according to your system paths and needs):

```
check process saslauth with pidfile /var/run/saslauthd/saslauthd.pid
    group mail
    start program = "/etc/init.d/saslauthd start"
    stop program = "/etc/init.d/saslauthd stop"
    if cpu > 90% for 2 cycles then restart
```

Where (taken from the manual):

```
CPU([user|system|wait]) is the percent of time the system spend in user or 
kernel space and I/O. The user/system/wait modifier is optional, if not 
used, the total system cpu usage is tested
```

And a *cycle* is is equal to the number of seconds in the `set daemon` config options.

Comment: Is there any script to automate it ? I just want to run "systemctl restart saslauthd" as soon as it reaches 100% CPU. I am just slightly uncomfortable with monit.

Comment: @AnandShrestha see my edits. It's all automatic if `monit` is configured right. You obviously need to use the correct paths and commands for your system.